# Why doesn't y=x work for arrays?

Tags: c

Why won't the following C code compile? It seems like it should just change the pointers' address but it throws an error.

```
int x[10];
int y[10];
y=x;
```

Comment: Looking at the compiler's error message usually helps in determining what goes wrong. In my case it complains that the left operand must be an l-value.

Comment: Well I know how to fix it, I more so wanted to know "why" it was invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x` and `y` are arrays, not pointers. In C, arrays can't change size or location; only their contents can change. You can't assign arrays directly.

If you want a pointer to one of the arrays you can declare one like this.

```
int *z = x;
```

If you need to assign an array you can create a struct that contains an array. `struct`s are assignable in C.

Comment: In the past I've used C compilers that allowed you to change array pointers. It's nice to see it is now verboten. Gives me hope.

Answer (score 7):

What pointers? You have two arrays. Arrays are not pointers. Pointers hold the address of a single variable in memory, while arrays are a contiguous collection of elements up to a specified size.

That said, arrays cannot be assigned. Conceivably, saying `y = x` could copy every element from `x` into `y`, but such a thing is dangerous (accidentally do an expensive operation with something as simple looking as an assignment). You can do it manually, though:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    y[i] = x[i];
```

Answer (score 4):

y is statically allocated. You can't change where it points.

Answer (score 1):

Because an array is (has) a pointer *value* (rvalue) but is not a pointer *variable* (lvalue).

```
int a[10];
int *p;
p = a;   // OK
a = p;   // Compile Error
```

Comment: To be obnoxiously pedantic, the type of an array *expression* is implicitly converted from "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T" (in most contexts).  Arrays are not pointers, and do not have pointer values.

Comment: @John: I'm not even sure if there is a contradiction here. I was using an older vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

y is not a "pointer", but a fixed array. You should consider it as a "constant of type int *", so you can't change a constant's value

Regards

Comment: I like the way you think of an array!

Comment: It's not very precise to think of it that way, because `&array` gives you a pointer to an array, not a pointer-to-a-pointer (which is a completely different beast, and not interchangeable).

Comment: True. My analogy between arrays and constants is only a sort of "mnemonic trick". It fails if applied strictly: consider that, while "&array" is perfectly legal, "&1234" doesn't have any sense, and it's indeed illegal.